# Web Socket & Arduino TIAN

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino

I think I have a huge confusion in the head. I'm trying to create node-js of scripts that read arduino values and send them to a websoket server ..

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

seems u looking for something like Johnny-Five or Firmata.. but depends on how you like to create your project.. give us more information please

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you: https://github.com/ideino/ideino-linino-lib

no Johnny-Five is required!

install before nodejs on your Arduino Tian, then create your .js file and use the ideino-linino-lib to access to the GPIO of your Arduino with nodejs.

When this work you can program your Tian with nodejs, and use all the npm packages (depending on your node version)